# Converting existing password hash to Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to convert an existing Admin model to Devise. We already have a password hash but it's obviously not Devise compatible. What I would like to do is accept the login form and check the provided password against the encrypted password. If it's not correct, use the old hash to check the password and if it matches, empty the old password_hash field and set Devise's password to the provided password and save the model.

What's the best way to move forward? I suspect that I need to override something, perhaps in a custom controller, but I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can let Devise do the "hard work" of encrypting the password with the new crypt scheme, as shown in https://gist.github.com/1704632:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?

  def valid_password?(password)
    begin
      super(password)
    rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
      return false unless Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) == encrypted_password
      logger.info "User #{email} is using the old password hashing method, updating attribute."
      self.password = password
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I was getting a stack level too deep error in testing this, and replaced devise_valid_password?(password) on the line after begin with just super -- seemed to work better...

Comment: This almost did it for me, I just need to change the Digestion:
`digest = "#{password}#{password_salt}"`
`20.times { digest = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(digest) }`
`return false unless digest == encrypted_password`

Comment: Nice solution, though I also needed a slight modification - I had been using an earlier version of Devise which created salted SHA1 hashes. My check looks like this: `digest = ""` `10.times { 
        digest = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("--" << [password_salt, digest, password, nil].flatten.join("--") << "--")
      }` 
      `return false unless digest == encrypted_password`

Comment: Will this work also with the standard has_secure_password with Bcrypt implementation?

Comment: If you were using `has_secure_password` from rails, change `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password)` to `BCrypt::Password.new(password)`

Comment: You should be using `Devise.secure_compare` rather than `==` on those passwords

Comment: Why you keep alias ... statement? Just in case you'd like to call the old method some day or is it important here (I don't think so)?

Answer (score 4):

Using the bcrypt encryptor in Devise, this is what I ended up doing with my legacy data:

**In models/user.rb**

```
# Because we have some old legacy users in the database, we need to override Devises method for checking if a password is valid.
# We first ask Devise if the password is valid, and if it throws an InvalidHash exception, we know that we're dealing with a
# legacy user, so we check the password against the SHA1 algorithm that was used to hash the password in the old database.
alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?
def valid_password?(password)
  begin
    devise_valid_password?(password)
  rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(password) == encrypted_password
  end
end
```

As you can see, devise throws an InvalidHash exception when it encounters an invalid hash, which it would do when authenticating a legacy user.
I use this to fall back to the hashing-algorithm used to create the original legacy hash.

It doesn't change the password though, but that could simply be added to the method if needed.

Comment: One side effect of someone trying lots of usernames on your site might be very high cpu usage as they've inadvertently causing the conversion to happen. Aah never mind it doesn't convert it.  So old users will still be insecure... But still a very clever low-effort answer, I like it

Answer (score 3):

First you need to copy password_salt and encrypted_password to your new object model

Using this because I have to export my database User to another application and old, 
 app are using devise 1.0.x and new app using 2.1.x

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?
    def valid_password?(password)
      begin
        devise_valid_password?(password)
      rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
        salt = password_salt
        digest = nil
        10.times { digest = ::Digest::SHA1.hexdigest('--' << [salt, digest, password, nil].flatten.join('--') << '--') }
        digest
        return false unless digest == encrypted_password
        logger.info "User #{email} is using the old password hashing method, updating attribute."
        self.password = password
        self.password_salt = nil # With this you will knew what object already using the new authentication by devise
        self.save
        true
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're moving from SHA512, the solution is a bit more involved than [moeffju's SHA1 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079088/7596):

```
def valid_password?(password)
  if has_legacy_password?
    return false unless valid_legacy_password?(password)
    convert_legacy_password!(password)
    true
  else
    super(password)
  end
end

protected

def has_legacy_password?
  password_salt.present?
end

def convert_legacy_password!(password)
  self.password = password
  self.password_salt = nil
  self.save
end

def valid_legacy_password?(password)
  stretches = 10
  salt = password_salt
  pepper = nil
  digest = pepper

  stretches.times do
    tokens = [salt, digest, password, pepper]
    digest = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest('--' << tokens.flatten.join('--') << '--')
  end

  Devise.secure_compare(encrypted_password, digest)
end
```

Be sure to replace `stretches` and `pepper` with the values you used to encrypt the passwords.

Answer (score -2):

follow Thomas Dippel instructions i have made a gist that update password:
https://gist.github.com/1578362

```
    # Because we have some old legacy users in the database, we need to override Devises method for checking if a password is valid.
# We first ask Devise if the password is valid, and if it throws an InvalidHash exception, we know that we're dealing with a
# legacy user, so we check the password against the SHA1 algorithm that was used to hash the password in the old database.
#SOURCES OF SOLUTION:
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113375/converting-existing-password-hash-to-devise
# https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/crypto_providers/sha512.rb
# https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/encryptors/authlogic_sha512.rb

alias :devise_valid_password? :valid_password?
def valid_password?(password)
  debugger
  begin
    devise_valid_password?(password)
  rescue BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash
    stretches = 20
    digest = [password, self.password_salt].flatten.join('')
    stretches.times {digest = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(digest)}
    if digest == self.encrypted_password
      #Here update old Authlogic SHA512 Password with new Devise ByCrypt password
      # SOURCE: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb
      # Digests the password using bcrypt.
      # Default strategy for Devise is BCrypt
      # def password_digest(password)
      # ::BCrypt::Password.create("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", :cost => self.class.stretches).to_s
      # end
      self.encrypted_password = self.password_digest(password)
      self.save
      return true
    else
      # If not BCryt password and not old Authlogic SHA512 password Dosn't my user
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can just use "self.password = password" and let Devise handle all that encryption stuff internally.

Comment: I think isn't possible because i want to use BCrypt as encriptor but my passwork are encripted with authlogic sha512

Comment: It's possible; I've done it. For example: https://gist.github.com/1704632 is all you need. Validate against SHA, and update to Bcrypt.

Comment: Thanks moeffju for your response. I'm doing wrong. i'm doing extra work. Where is defined `encrypted_password`?

Comment: Devise provides the `encrypted_password` method on your user model.