# Transferring users from Devise 1.1.7 to 2.2.3, for new application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I develop a new application and I want to transfer users from old one. I'd like to let them to use their own old password in new app.

```
OLD_APP:
  config.encryptor = :authlogic_sha512
  config.pepper = "xxx"

  devise (1.1.7)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 2.1.2)
  warden (~> 1.0.2)

NEW_APP:
devise (2.2.3)
  bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
  orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
  railties (~> 3.1)
  warden (~> 1.2.1)

BCrypt
without pepper (config.pepper line left commented)
```

I used some solutions such as:
[Converting existing password hash to Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113375/converting-existing-password-hash-to-devise)

but unfortunately it doesn't works.
My questions is how I could transform `SHA512` hash (with salt) to `BCrypt` (without salt) ?
Whether anybody came across on this issue ?

Thanks.